# AS3 gotoAndStop() not working and making trace() not work also

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have three buttons that are supposed to toggle when clicked on and off. All three have the same code, but only the first one is working.

Each button jumps to a different frame where that specific button is "toggled" and then if clicked again it should be able to jump back to the main menu, which I've labeled "main."

When I click on buttons B (and C but I'm just referring to B as an example), it traces "B was selected" like it's supposed to, but when I click again, nothing happens. It doesn't trace "B was deselected" or gotoAndStop() on frame "main" like it's supposed to. When I remove the gotoAndStop() lines from buttons B and C, it runs correctly, tracing "B was selected" and then "B was deselected" when toggled on and off.

I have absolutely no idea why buttons B and C don't work and I've rewritten the code so many times.

Any help anyone can give me would be appreciated very much!!

```
   stop();

var a:int;
a=0;
var b:int;
b=0;
var c:int;
c=0;

var hitA:Boolean=false;

btnA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AHandler);
function AHandler(e:Object):void {
    if (hitA==false) {
        hitA=true; 
    }
    if(a==0){
        trace("A was selected");
        gotoAndStop("Aup");
        a=1
        } else {
                trace("A was deselected");
                a=0;
                gotoAndStop("main");
    }
}


//////Button B

var hitB:Boolean=false;

btnB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, BHandler);
function BHandler(e:Object):void {
    if (hitB==false) {
        hitB=true;
    }
    if(b==0){
        trace("B was selected");
        gotoAndStop("Bup");
        b=1
        } else {
                trace("B was deselected");
                b=0;
                gotoAndStop("main");
    }
}

//////Button C


var hitC:Boolean=false;

btnC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, CHandler);
function CHandler(e:Object):void {
    if (hitC==false) {
        hitC=true; 
    }
    if(c==0){
        trace("C was selected");
        gotoAndStop("Cup");
        c=1
        } else {
                trace("C was deselected");
                c=0;
                gotoAndStop("main");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I did timeline coding but try placing your code in its own layer that only has one keyframe and spans throughout your entire timeline. So if "Aup" is frame 1, "Bup" is frame 3, "Cup" is frame 7, your code layer should be from frame 1 to frame 7.

Comment: @TreeTree I have all the code on frame one of a layer called "actions." Each label is keyframed on different frames though.

Comment: If your code only exists on one frame, nothing will happen when you go to a different frame because there's no code there. I suspect that's what's happening. You described that the buttons only work the very first time you click them.

Comment: TreeTree is right, if you converted your code into the document class, you would not have this problem.

Comment: @Xiler I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean. The "document class?"

Comment: See my answer as i attempt to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The document class]

This picture highlights where you specify your document class for your project. This class is an actionscript file (.as) and like all .as files they contain code. It is the same code that you put on timelines, except .as are just separate from the .fla file but can still be connected to it. When writing code to .as files you just have to put it all in a package and then a class, but besides that you can just copy and past your code in. If it is in the document class, it will be running no matter what frame your timeline is on.

```
package{
  public class{
    // your code here
  }
}
```

If this is still confusing then just look it up, there are plenty of great books on pretty much anything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code...

```
btnA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AHandler);
function AHandler(e:Object):void {
    if (hitA==false) {
        hitA=true; 
    }

btnA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, Adouble);
function Adouble(e:Object):void {
    gotoAndStop("main");
```